# Difference between ssl products and recommented ssl

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, wildcard

I need more information on SSL certificate.

[image: SSL with Cross line (Red)]

[image: Normal SSL]

[image: Green SSL without EV]

[image: Green SSL with EV]

I am using AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14 with LAMP. I looked for OpenSSL as I do not have budget but it acts like first one. I need SSL which can acts like second one or third one.

More importantly, I need SSL which can work on sub-domains as well (Single Domain with Wildcard) or multiple domain on Single Server.

Can anyone suggest one which will cost less on my pocket.

Answer (score 4):

https://letsencrypt.org/

This is a new CA that is currently in public beta, trusted by all modern browsers, and completely free. It is worth your time to check it out.

Comment: Please note: Let's Encrypt doesn't sign wildcard certs. Instead you have to get a cert combining all your domains or one cert per domain. I would advise to go for the first route, as it makes the management (in my opinion) easier.